# Closure is not subsettable in datadist$limits

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm not entirely sure why I am receiving this error when using the `rms` package  and the `ols()` function to do a simple multi-variable regression.  The `lm()` function works fine.

**Error:**

> Error in datadist$limits : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

**Sample Data:**

```
dat <- structure(list(value = c(153.7, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 
137.2, 137.2, 137.2, 144.3), x1 = c(1586.30574782368, 1827.63764435891, 
1274.37779664208, 1470.22193641518, 1424.71486797217, 1588.96099774091, 
1768.09933607758, 1447.4030640002, 1586.11159875168, 1741.04342002899
), x2 = c(9.37073885963036, 79.466637406771, 3.07432642677304, 
5.32614246511366, 9.65257915442635, 9.70809241832467, 47.0161105721418, 
39.7744598414865, 13.2940602286908, 26.6250313249184)), .Names = c("value", 
"x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Model using `ols`:**

```
library(rms)
datadist <- datadist(dat)
options("datadist" = "datadist")

mod <- ols(log(value) ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

> mod <- ols(log(value) ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
Error in datadist$limits : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

**Model using `lm`:**

```
> mod <- lm(log(value) ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = log(value) ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.032746 -0.021049 -0.004316  0.010937  0.080848 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.7514306  0.1487970   31.93 7.64e-09 ***
x1           0.0001335  0.0001019    1.31    0.232    
x2          -0.0009582  0.0007205   -1.33    0.225    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03755 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2261,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.004997 
F-statistic: 1.023 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.4077
```

Comment: `datadist` is a function and the `$` operator is not defined for functions (closures).   (that's what "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" is saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `datadist()` by calling your data `"datadist"`.  Try this instead:

```
d <- datadist(dat)
options(datadist = "d")  ## don't need quotes around argument name ...
mod <- ols(log(value) ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
```

With respect to Frank Harrell, the author of `rms` (whose *Regression Modeling Strategies* book is fantastic), this way of saving options (i.e., saving the *name* of an object and retrieving it from the environment by name) is a bit delicate and likely to get screwed up in situations like this.

This kind of problem is also why experienced R users suggest *not* masking names of functions (`datadist()`) by giving other objects the same name (`datadist`). R is *usually* clever enough to figure out what you mean anyway, but on the relatively rare occasions where it gets confused, the symptoms are often obscure and hard to debug. (This is also why you shouldn't name your data frame `data` or `df` ...)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm slowly reading the book and learning the package, so these issues are coming up as I work through it.  Thanks for the help.